# IE SVG4601 Error with SVG as data URL

Tags: javascript, svg

I finished my personal website today (yey), but of course it doesn't work in IE. I wouldn't bother, if it wouldn't be for employers so my question is the following.

When I try to open the Yes I Code page the IE gives me an error message saying

```
SVG4601: SVG Path data has incorrect format and could not be completely parsed.
```

After googeling a bit, I found a few ideas that might help, but I am not generating the svg dynamically. The SVG is a data url generated via webpack from a file.

This is one of the many SVG files https://pastebin.com/En4YQwzC

This is the code that loads it via require

```
{
  name: 'SQLite',
  logo: require('../src/assets/logos/database/sqlite-seeklogo.com.svg'),
  parent: [
    'Database'
  ]
},
```

And this is the Vue.js component that renders the svg:

```
<template>
  <div class="ulbricht-yes-i-code">
    <div class="ulbricht-yes-i-code__framework-item" v-for="framework in frameworks" :key="framework.name">
      <img class="ulbricht-yes-i-code__framework-logo" :src="dataUrl(framework.logo)" :alt="framework.name"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import YesICode from 'the file with all svg images';

  export default {
    name: "YesICode",
    computed: {
      yesICode() {
        return YesICode;
      },
      frameworks() {
        return YesICode.frameworks.filter(item => item.parent.includes(this.selectedGroup));
      }
    },
    methods: {
      dataUrl(input) {
        return `data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,${encodeURIComponent(input.replace(/"/g, '\''))}`;
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        selectedGroup: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The SVG gets injected into the DOM but is not displayed at all. Here is the rendered img tag

```
<img class="ulbricht-yes-i-code__framework-logo" alt="SQLite" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20512%20228'%20version%3D'1.1'%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20preserveAspectRatio%3D'xMidYMid'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient%20x1%3D'57.6615627%25'%20y1%3D'2.04644676%25'%20x2%3D'57.6615584%25'%20y2%3D'94.4387516%25'%20id%3D'linearGradient-1'%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'%2397D9F6'%20offset%3D'0%25'%3E%3C%2Fstop%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'%230F80CC'%20offset%3D'92.024499%25'%3E%3C%2Fstop%3E%3Cstop%20stop-color%3D'%230F80CC'%20offset%3D'100%25'%3E%3C%2Fstop%3E%3C%2FlinearGradient%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M194.519337%2C112.044206%20C187.698564%2C112.044206%20182.152486%2C114.063211%20177.900552%2C118.099455%20C173.648619%2C122.139234%20171.491713%2C127.434452%20171.491713%2C133.922666%20C171.491713%2C137.285148%20172.027403%2C140.350953%20173.082873%2C143.160235%20C174.138343%2C145.975174%20175.780773%2C148.582909%20177.98895%2C150.939241%20C180.197127%2C153.297694%20184.617017%2C156.501413%20191.20442%2C160.5746%20C199.287514%2C165.509134%20204.577238%2C169.513908%20207.116022%2C172.640884%20C209.656575%2C175.765215%20210.917127%2C179.03947%20210.917127%2C182.453039%20C210.917127%2C187.023558%20209.412597%2C190.671912%20206.320442%2C193.414365%20C203.222983%2C196.158062%20199.080663%2C197.524862%20193.944751%2C197.524862%20C188.527735%2C197.524862%20183.809061%2C195.6153%20179.756906%2C191.823204%20C175.704751%2C188.025635%20173.659227%2C183.002703%20173.61326%2C176.707182%20L171.093923%2C176.707182%20L171.093923%2C199.558011%20L173.61326%2C199.558011%20C174.38232%2C197.394203%20175.44663%2C196.287293%20176.839779%2C196.287293%20C177.509834%2C196.287293%20179.079779%2C196.749436%20181.524862%2C197.61326%20C187.474033%2C199.730026%20192.358895%2C200.751381%20196.198895%2C200.751381%20C202.816354%2C200.751381%20208.464972%2C198.433775%20213.171271%2C193.723757%20C217.870497%2C189.015874%20220.243094%2C183.337017%20220.243094%2C176.707182%20C220.243094%2C171.56632%20218.676685%2C166.992435%20215.60221%2C163.005539%20C212.527735%2C159.013848%20206.548508%2C154.370829%20197.61326%2C149.038688%20C189.92442%2C144.419175%20184.933481%2C140.65681%20182.629834%2C137.723771%20C180.322652%2C134.794961%20179.138122%2C131.555204%20179.138122%2C128.000014%20C179.138122%2C124.154703%20180.550718%2C121.066084%20183.337017%2C118.762438%20C186.123315%2C116.457024%20189.774144%2C115.314924%20194.342541%2C115.314924%20C199.483757%2C115.314924%20203.769282%2C116.84067%20207.160221%2C119.911609%20C210.547624%2C122.987852%20212.506519%2C127.250747%20213.082873%2C132.729296%20L215.60221%2C132.729296%20L215.60221%2C112.928184%20L213.259669%2C112.928184%20C212.97326%2C113.937687%20212.708066%2C114.58299%20212.464088%2C114.872935%20C212.227182%2C115.161112%20211.77105%2C115.314924%20211.093923%2C115.314924%20C210.278895%2C115.314924%20208.825635%2C114.971941%20206.762431%2C114.29835%20C202.342541%2C112.809731%20198.267403%2C112.044206%20194.519337%2C112.044206%20L194.519337%2C112.044206%20Z%20M276.861878%2C112.044206%20C268.550718%2C112.044206%20261.005083%2C114.003101%20254.187845%2C117.922659%20C247.36%2C121.835145%20241.955359%2C127.268073%20237.966851%2C134.187859%20C233.98011%2C141.107101%20232%2C148.455772%20232%2C156.287307%20C232%2C166.808751%20235.443978%2C176.182269%20242.38674%2C184.39779%20C249.333039%2C192.608361%20257.656575%2C197.724471%20267.314917%2C199.690608%20C269.523094%2C200.841193%20272.682431%2C203.811359%20276.81768%2C208.618785%20C281.478011%2C214.044103%20285.420552%2C217.957127%20288.662983%2C220.287293%20C291.901878%2C222.618689%20295.398895%2C224.327425%20299.093923%2C225.458564%20C302.792486%2C226.584935%20306.791602%2C227.138122%20311.116022%2C227.138122%20C316.352707%2C227.138122%20321.041326%2C226.227978%20325.171271%2C224.353591%20L324.243094%2C222.055249%20C321.845746%2C222.919963%20319.289282%2C223.337017%20316.596685%2C223.337017%20C312.94232%2C223.337017%20309.249061%2C222.131978%20305.546961%2C219.712707%20C301.850166%2C217.287425%20297.226961%2C212.660162%20291.712707%2C205.834254%20C289.120884%2C202.563536%20287.331713%2C200.499978%20286.320442%2C199.690608%20C296.887514%2C197.62705%20305.577017%2C192.505635%20312.353591%2C184.309392%20C319.128398%2C176.116685%20322.519337%2C166.766518%20322.519337%2C156.287307%20C322.519337%2C143.84459%20318.092376%2C133.387499%20309.303867%2C124.861886%20C300.508287%2C116.335388%20289.691934%2C112.044206%20276.861878%2C112.044206%20L276.861878%2C112.044206%20Z%20M328.265193%2C112.044206%20L328.397719%2C114.740339%20C333.931421%2C114.740339%20337.030648%2C116.370394%20337.723686%2C119.646416%20C337.981808%2C120.818571%20338.100261%2C122.982902%20338.121476%2C126.099455%20L338.077348%2C185.723757%20C338.031381%2C190.176884%20337.396685%2C193.02011%20336.176796%2C194.254144%20C334.955138%2C195.479337%20332.890166%2C196.24663%20329.900552%2C196.552486%20L329.768027%2C199.248619%20L384.928248%2C199.248619%20L386.342612%2C185.723757%20L383.823275%2C185.723757%20C383.103717%2C189.408177%20381.454214%2C192.047565%20378.8288%2C193.546961%20C376.196314%2C195.057319%20371.541286%2C195.801105%20364.81775%2C195.801105%20L359.602281%2C195.801105%20C353.552336%2C195.801105%20350.051783%2C193.61396%20349.127143%2C189.21547%20C348.936203%2C188.345282%20348.870789%2C187.412324%20348.861949%2C186.38674%20L349.082944%2C126.099455%20C349.081529%2C121.653399%20349.643386%2C118.67404%20350.806701%2C117.215477%20C351.982391%2C115.762217%20354.10217%2C114.948957%20357.171341%2C114.740339%20L357.038815%2C112.044206%20L328.265335%2C112.044206%20L328.265193%2C112.044206%20Z%20M277.745856%2C115.314924%20C287.119558%2C115.314924%20294.773039%2C119.00677%20300.685083%2C126.453046%20C306.595359%2C133.901988%20309.524862%2C144.111211%20309.524862%2C157.038688%20C309.524862%2C169.288656%20306.552928%2C179.097289%20300.596685%2C186.475138%20C294.640442%2C193.850696%20286.712928%2C197.524862%20276.861878%2C197.524862%20C267.398011%2C197.524862%20259.723315%2C193.736133%20253.834254%2C186.121547%20C247.950497%2C178.506961%20245.038674%2C168.620906%20245.038674%2C156.464103%20C245.038674%2C143.971727%20247.985856%2C133.971631%20253.922652%2C126.497245%20C259.855912%2C119.030814%20267.801105%2C115.314924%20277.745856%2C115.314924%20L277.745856%2C115.314924%20Z%20M404.596685%2C128.132611%20C403.251271%2C128.132611%20402.225856%2C128.586975%20401.458564%2C129.502777%20C400.673591%2C130.415028%20400.433149%2C131.52%20400.707182%2C132.861893%20C400.972376%2C134.163631%20401.706077%2C135.3045%20402.872928%2C136.265208%20C404.032707%2C137.22501%20405.28442%2C137.723771%20406.629834%2C137.723771%20C407.93105%2C137.723771%20408.922873%2C137.225038%20409.635359%2C136.265208%20C410.347845%2C135.3045%20410.565304%2C134.163631%20410.298343%2C132.861893%20C410.024309%2C131.52%20409.315359%2C130.415028%20408.220994%2C129.502777%20C407.114254%2C128.586975%20405.897901%2C128.132611%20404.596685%2C128.132611%20L404.596685%2C128.132611%20Z%20M440.972376%2C137.281782%20C438.686409%2C146.075934%20433.730829%2C150.834917%20426.121547%2C151.602224%20L426.209945%2C154.121561%20L435.093923%2C154.121561%20L434.917127%2C183.911602%20C434.931271%2C189.004729%20435.086851%2C192.395669%20435.447514%2C194.121547%20C436.322652%2C198.253444%20439.020552%2C200.353591%20443.535912%2C200.353591%20C450.068508%2C200.353591%20456.921105%2C196.374276%20464.088398%2C188.41989%20L461.922652%2C186.563536%20C456.747845%2C191.801819%20452.172376%2C194.430939%20448.176796%2C194.430939%20C445.721105%2C194.430939%20444.198895%2C193.018696%20443.624309%2C190.232044%20C443.466961%2C189.555271%20443.403315%2C188.764471%20443.403315%2C187.845304%20L443.491713%2C154.121561%20L457.060773%2C154.121561%20L456.928248%2C150.099462%20L443.535982%2C150.099462%20L443.535982%2C137.281782%20L440.972446%2C137.281782%20L440.972376%2C137.281782%20Z%20M493.436464%2C148.508301%20C485.84663%2C148.508301%20479.672928%2C152.192721%20474.872928%2C159.513826%20C470.09768%2C166.847307%20468.619669%2C174.97228%20470.497238%2C183.911602%20C471.60221%2C189.14775%20473.803315%2C193.20593%20477.171271%2C196.066298%20C480.533923%2C198.925436%20484.8%2C200.353591%20489.900552%2C200.353591%20C494.649282%2C200.353591%20501.261436%2C199.151211%20504.044199%2C196.729282%20C506.834033%2C194.308766%20509.404641%2C190.38744%20511.779006%2C185.016575%20L509.878453%2C183.027624%20C506.091492%2C189.995138%20498.448619%2C193.502762%20492.685083%2C193.502762%20C484.761105%2C193.502762%20479.908066%2C189.155359%20478.099448%2C180.508287%20C477.864309%2C179.404545%20477.689282%2C178.218785%20477.569061%2C176.972376%20C486.995801%2C175.479867%20494.14011%2C172.836943%20498.961326%2C169.016575%20C503.779006%2C165.194099%20508.616133%2C161.142283%20507.712707%2C156.861893%20C507.175249%2C154.318328%20505.854586%2C152.318416%20503.823204%2C150.806644%20C501.765304%2C149.295579%20496.422541%2C148.508301%20493.436464%2C148.508301%20L493.436464%2C148.508301%20Z%20M410.475138%2C148.817694%20L394.121547%2C152.5746%20L394.121547%2C155.491727%20L399.779006%2C154.784545%20C402.519337%2C154.784545%20404.131713%2C156.02548%20404.640884%2C158.497252%20C404.812376%2C159.324485%20404.920221%2C160.486202%20404.950276%2C161.944766%20L404.773481%2C188.685083%20C404.727514%2C192.385414%20404.317348%2C194.536479%20403.491713%2C195.18232%20C402.659006%2C195.829392%20400.463204%2C196.154696%20396.906077%2C196.154696%20L396.81768%2C198.674033%20L422.762431%2C198.674033%20L422.718303%2C196.154696%20C419.113441%2C196.154696%20416.776203%2C195.870239%20415.734877%2C195.314917%20C414.711231%2C194.763145%20414.005817%2C193.758946%20413.701728%2C192.220994%20C413.46659%2C191.112656%20413.364049%2C189.202924%20413.348137%2C186.563536%20L413.436535%2C148.817694%20L410.475209%2C148.817694%20L410.475138%2C148.817694%20Z%20M489.281768%2C153.76797%20C490.860552%2C153.76797%20492.386298%2C154.377731%20493.922652%2C155.580125%20C495.43779%2C156.778275%20496.360663%2C158.110593%20496.662983%2C159.558025%20C498.142762%2C166.667159%20491.84%2C171.582048%20477.657459%2C174.320442%20C477.252597%2C169.136626%20478.150718%2C164.430865%20480.441989%2C160.17681%20C482.71558%2C155.926814%20485.676906%2C153.76797%20489.281768%2C153.76797%20L489.281768%2C153.76797%20Z'%20fill%3D'%23003B57'%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M157.887646%2C9.95179492%20L17.1498785%2C9.95179492%20C7.71748066%2C9.95179492%201.42108547e-14%2C17.6706899%201.42108547e-14%2C27.1027341%20L1.42108547e-14%2C182.31016%20C1.42108547e-14%2C191.741666%207.71748066%2C199.459331%2017.1498785%2C199.459331%20L109.843448%2C199.459331%20C108.79135%2C153.338017%20124.54117%2C63.8308448%20157.887646%2C9.95179492%20L157.887646%2C9.95179492%20Z'%20fill%3D'%230F80CC'%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M152.774718%2C14.9551098%20L17.1498785%2C14.9551098%20C10.4523315%2C14.9551098%205.00207735%2C20.4039496%205.00207735%2C27.1027341%20L5.00207735%2C170.986233%20C35.7181878%2C159.197504%2081.8193467%2C149.025535%20113.695413%2C149.487509%20C120.100971%2C115.994079%20138.926844%2C50.3540911%20152.774718%2C14.9551098%20L152.774718%2C14.9551098%20Z'%20fill%3D'url(%23linearGradient-1)'%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D'M190.71505%2C4.8724579%20C181.076155%2C-3.7233432%20169.405878%2C-0.270525525%20157.887646%2C9.95179492%20C156.178033%2C11.470469%20154.471956%2C13.1553308%20152.774718%2C14.9551098%20C133.070851%2C35.8576513%20114.781348%2C74.5758833%20109.099138%2C104.144944%20C111.312619%2C108.633784%20113.04168%2C114.361961%20114.180243%2C118.737651%20C114.471956%2C119.860303%20114.735381%2C120.914005%20114.945768%2C121.810358%20C115.446099%2C123.931729%20115.714829%2C125.307375%20115.714829%2C125.307375%20C115.714829%2C125.307375%20115.538033%2C124.638911%20114.813171%2C122.536988%20C114.675271%2C122.133894%20114.521459%2C121.693673%20114.339359%2C121.175662%20C114.261569%2C120.96174%20114.153724%2C120.70185%20114.035271%2C120.424281%20C112.749967%2C117.436436%20109.194608%2C111.130137%20107.629967%2C108.384502%20C106.291624%2C112.332347%20105.108862%2C116.025607%20104.118807%2C119.367044%20C108.635934%2C127.631883%20111.388641%2C141.795684%20111.388641%2C141.795684%20C111.388641%2C141.795684%20111.149967%2C140.877762%20110.014939%2C137.674056%20C109.007204%2C134.840546%20103.987978%2C126.046381%20102.799028%2C123.990425%20C100.765171%2C131.498587%2099.9570387%2C136.567669%20100.68579%2C137.801872%20C102.100685%2C140.193393%20103.448221%2C144.319802%20104.631514%2C148.88325%20C107.304663%2C159.163729%20109.162785%2C171.678918%20109.162785%2C171.678918%20C109.162785%2C171.678918%20109.222895%2C172.508259%20109.323669%2C173.784553%20C108.952398%2C182.417835%20109.17516%2C191.368811%20109.843448%2C199.459331%20C110.729193%2C210.169253%20112.396376%2C219.369526%20114.521459%2C224.293452%20L115.96411%2C223.506896%20C112.843669%2C213.805939%20111.576044%2C201.092568%20112.131182%2C186.430911%20C112.970961%2C164.020133%20118.128088%2C136.993747%20127.65737%2C108.824723%20C143.756376%2C66.3018502%20166.092729%2C32.1838391%20186.535602%2C15.8903585%20C167.903116%2C32.7177618%20142.684994%2C87.186712%20135.135823%2C107.35732%20C126.683227%2C129.944723%20120.693392%2C151.140929%20117.083227%2C171.4489%20C123.311735%2C152.410321%20143.450519%2C144.226624%20143.450519%2C144.226624%20C143.450519%2C144.226624%20153.328088%2C132.044885%20164.871072%2C114.641298%20C157.956597%2C116.218314%20146.602785%2C118.917983%20142.799912%2C120.516215%20C137.190188%2C122.869364%20135.678586%2C123.672016%20135.678586%2C123.672016%20C135.678586%2C123.672016%20153.849635%2C112.606381%20169.43947%2C107.595994%20C190.87947%2C73.828038%20214.237702%2C25.8563253%20190.71505%2C4.8724579'%20fill%3D'%23003B57'%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
```

I currently have no Windows environment for debugging, so it is a bit hard to tackle it down. My current environment is an Azure VM. You can check out the site here: https://imanuel.ulbricht.codes/yesicode

Any help is appreciated, maybe there is even a better way to generate the DataURLs. Loading the files via HTTP doesn't solve the problem.

**Update**

After removing all images except the Java logo I still get the error. The SVG of the Java logo is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 346" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <path d="M82.5539491,267.472524 C82.5539491,267.472524 69.35552,275.147869 91.9468218,277.745105 C119.315549,280.867375 133.303389,280.419607 163.463913,274.711273 C163.463913,274.711273 171.393396,279.683258 182.467491,283.989644 C114.855564,312.966982 29.4483782,282.311215 82.5539491,267.472524"
              fill="#5382A1"/>
        <path d="M74.2921309,229.658996 C74.2921309,229.658996 59.4888145,240.616727 82.0968727,242.955171 C111.333004,245.971316 134.421411,246.218007 174.373236,238.524975 C174.373236,238.524975 179.899113,244.127185 188.588218,247.190807 C106.841367,271.094691 15.79008,249.075898 74.2921309,229.658996"
              fill="#5382A1"/>
        <path d="M143.941818,165.514705 C160.601367,184.695156 139.564684,201.955142 139.564684,201.955142 C139.564684,201.955142 181.866124,180.117876 162.438982,152.772422 C144.294633,127.271098 130.380335,114.600495 205.706705,70.9138618 C205.706705,70.9138618 87.4691491,100.44416 143.941818,165.514705"
              fill="#E76F00"/>
        <path d="M233.364015,295.441687 C233.364015,295.441687 243.131113,303.489396 222.60736,309.715316 C183.580858,321.537862 60.1748945,325.107898 25.8932364,310.186356 C13.5698618,304.825251 36.67968,297.385425 43.9491491,295.824291 C51.5304727,294.180305 55.8629236,294.486575 55.8629236,294.486575 C42.15808,284.832116 -32.7195927,313.443607 17.8287709,321.637469 C155.681513,343.993251 269.121164,311.570618 233.364015,295.441687"
              fill="#5382A1"/>
        <path d="M88.9008873,190.479825 C88.9008873,190.479825 26.1287564,205.389265 66.6717091,210.803433 C83.7901964,213.095331 117.915462,212.576815 149.702284,209.913484 C175.680233,207.722124 201.765236,203.062924 201.765236,203.062924 C201.765236,203.062924 192.605091,206.985775 185.977949,211.510924 C122.233949,228.275665 -0.907636364,220.476509 34.5432436,203.328233 C64.5241018,188.83584 88.9008873,190.479825 88.9008873,190.479825"
              fill="#5382A1"/>
        <path d="M201.506444,r253.422313 C266.305164,219.7504 236.344785,187.392 215.432844,191.751447 C210.307258,192.818269 208.021876,193.742662 208.021876,193.742662 C208.021876,193.742662 209.924655,190.761891 213.558924,189.471651 C254.929455,174.927127 286.746065,232.368873 200.204102,255.11936 C200.204102,255.120291 201.206691,254.223825 201.506444,253.422313"
              fill="#5382A1"/>
        <path d="M162.438982,0.371432727 C162.438982,0.371432727 198.325527,36.27008 128.402153,91.4720582 C72.3307055,135.753542 115.616116,161.001658 128.37888,189.848669 C95.6490473,160.318371 71.6297309,134.322735 87.7437673,110.128407 C111.395375,74.6132945 176.918342,57.3942691 162.438982,0.371432727"
              fill="#E76F00"/>
        <path d="M95.2683055,344.665367 C157.466996,348.646865 252.980131,342.45632 255.24224,313.025629 C255.24224,313.025629 250.893964,324.182575 203.838371,333.042967 C150.750487,343.033484 85.2740655,341.867055 46.4393309,335.464262 C46.4402618,335.463331 54.3892945,342.043927 95.2683055,344.665367"
              fill="#5382A1"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

My current idea is, to detect the IE via UA and then displaying PNGs instead of SVG files. But I am unsure if that is really the only solution.

Comment: I'd recommend taking out lines from the SVG until it works, then work backwards from there. I wonder if it's not choking on `fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"`..

Comment: This one works on my VM on both IE11 and Edge. The one that doesn't work though is the MS SQL Server icon, which is sent by your server as *plain* instead of *image/svg+xml*.

Comment: @Kaiido, I forgot to deploy the version with inline SVG. No it is not served but inlined.

Comment: @Phix the part with the fill seems legit, I will test that.

Comment: I don't have my VM on anymore, but the inline version in your post worked on both IE11 an edge.

Comment: It gets even stranger, I updated my question.

Comment: The solution was rather dumb. The reported SVG error didn't have any effect. The issue is the handling of flexbox in IE. With that knowledge I was able to fix it.